# Changing Date time zone in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, types, momentjs

I have a date in UTC format `2020-06-19T03:55:12.000Z. Now i am converting into date of US timezone as

```js
let syncDate = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]')
    .subtract(7, 'hours')
    .format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]');
```

This gives me a date 7 hours behind which is date of US. But i want a date in below format

```
2020-06-18T21:00:24.523-07:00
```

Here if we can see the hours are defined as -7 so please guide how can we achieve the same ?

Comment: The datetime of USA varies on timezone in USA and is not fixed on 7 except where that is the case. Im not sure if you are aware of this. U.S. Has about 5 timezones which can be looked up.

Comment: I might also add that there is an advantage in keeping times in UTC; just in formatting the time for display purposes, or other logic for accounting, the conversion can take place without altering the UTC datetime stored.

Comment: In regards to your question, the sample data string (format) `2020-06-18T21:00:24.523-07:00 ` has two clear delimiters. The 1st is `T`. The 2nd appears to be of two possible values, a `-` or a `+`, following that is the hour difference from UTC.

Comment: So can we create such display like format ?

Comment: Well you can thru an easy or moreso convoluted method create a function that simulates the same. I just re-read your post and realized you are using *moment.js*. I would check their API docs first before reinventing the wheel. But in recap so we are on same page: the first token is the date in UTC, the second (after) the `T` is the time in UTC, and the 3rd after the `-` or `+` is the difference (to bring it to the target time zone)?

Comment: OP: How is `This gives me a date 7 hours behind which is date of US`. Can you update your post on how *that* datetime string is formatted? You show your after (desired) but not your before.

Answer (score 2):

You can't extract a timezone out of your date because there is no timezone information in it. You said "I am converting into a date of US timezone as" But you didn't. You just reduced it for 7 hours. The timezone is still UTC.

You should use `moment-timezone` (not handling things the hard way and manually as @GetSet said). Here the solution:

```
const moment = require('moment'); 
const tz = require('moment-timezone');

let date = moment('2020-06-19T03:55:12.000Z');
let syncDate = date.tz('America/Los_Angeles')
console.log(syncDate.format());
```

But, I suggest you use **`Day.js`**. The code will be:

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
const utc = require('dayjs/plugin/utc');
dayjs.extend(utc);

const dDate = dayjs('2020-06-19T03:55:12.000Z');

console.log(dDate.utcOffset(-7*60).format()); //2020-06-18T20:55:12-07:00
```

I used `moment.js` in the past. I tried `Date-fnd` for 24 hours. And finally, I moved to [Day.js](https://day.js.org). It's new (start in late 2018) but it's growing so quick ([take a look at this link](https://www.npmtrends.com/date-fns-vs-dayjs-vs-moment) and put the duration on 5 years). The great thing about it is that "**IT ALWAYS DOES WHAT IT SAYS**". Moment and Date-fns don't. (not always). It uses a wrapper and so you never work with the Date object directly. It solves difficulties and problems. It's **immutable** and always returns a new object and you can chain functions. Day.js has the smallest size (2kB).The documentation is awesome and you can up and running very fast. (It's more understandable that the way other libraries work.)

Here I have to say that `Dayjs` performance is not is good as Moment in calculations but is way better (than especially moment) in parsing and formating.

I strongly suggest you read this article: [Why you shouldn't use Moment.js](https://inventi.studio/en/blog/why-you-shouldnt-use-moment-js)

---

Edit(1): As @GetSet mentioned in comments for OP that may need a solution in Moment.js I added it to the answer.

Edit(2): Adding the reason why you can't achieve your result the way OP solving it.

Comment: OP may have dependencies on *moment.js*; further where applicable OP may be willing to explore the underlining problem further before exploring competitive APIs. However in reading your code block, seems sound. The difference would be that (Day.js) gives fractional seconds in decimals (times 100?) whereas OP's gives fractional seconds as a percentage ( < 1).

Comment: Good advice. I'd like to suggest to you tho that you prepend additions to your post on why you made the edit. So that comments don't become obsolete to your answer.

Comment: @GetSet I'm sorry. But I'm not native English and the way you writing is a little hard for me to understand. :) what OP means? (It seems it is not the matter of English but a programming phrase?!)

Comment: *OP* means the person who started the thread on this site. OP = "Original Poster". The person who posted the question. Whereas "we" are not the OP. So as a general rule, we have to direct questions or comments for further "help" in understanding the actual problem thru the OP's feedback.

Comment: @GetSet Tnx! a lot! :) You are right, completely. I put it because of some times a switch worth it (like in my case I replace everything in my code and removed Moment). But no offense. I agreed with you. Also about "I'd like to suggest to you tho that you prepend additions to...", I thank you because I'm new to answering and these guidances will help me much. I saw other do it, but have you a link on how to do it? (I know we should now discuss under this question)

Comment: @TechChain Did your problem solved? If yes pls mark the answer as correct. If no, provide me more info so I can help you.

Comment: Armamedia ,,, im just realizing that OP wants advice for this in moment.js: `But i want a date in below format`, so looks to be a formatting question.

Answer (score 1):

1. `new Date()` depends on local computer date setup - if any user has wrong date on his local computer - your system will take wrong dates from those users.
2. If you working with dates on background (storing in database or any other manipulations) - generate it on background (php, java etc.) and than send it to you html/javascript files.

Comment: `and than send it to you html/javascript files` ... good advice. If its a properly configured server (even a hosted server) then the UTC timestamp from them could serve as the basis to establish the correct current UTC on the client's end per your `send it to you html/javascript files`. Being that as you say the user's datetime is anyone's guess per browser javascript. Upvote but `new Date()` has its limitations for further manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Date().toLocalString()` method

```
// example:
var d = new Date().toLocalString("en-US", {
    month: "long",
    day: "2-digit",
    year: "numeric",
});
```

for more information see:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp

Comment: Nope. You are talking about different thing. 
1. `toLocaleString`, not `toLocalString`
2. This function only formating date.
See example https://codepen.io/stewardtz/pen/NWxdjKL

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things it is vitally important to point out here.

1. There is no one US timezone, there are quite a few, for example America/Los_Angeles, America/Denver, America/Chicago, America/New_York, see the [IANA Timezone list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for all of them.
2. Please don't convert from one timezone to another using a *fixed* offset, this is really fragile. You wouldn't believe how many bugs I've seen in my career (from others, and yes, from myself!) due to this one mistake. Many timezones use [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), so the UTC offset of the timezone varies by the date. For example, the [Pacific Timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone) *currently* varies between UTC-08:00 and UTC-07:00.

I would suggest using [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to convert from one timezone to another.

For example:

```js
const dateString = `2020-06-19T03:55:12.000Z`;
const timezones = ["America/New_York", "America/Chicago", "America/Denver", "America/Los_Angeles"];

console.log(`Time in UTC:`, moment(dateString).toISOString());

// Show the time in each timezone
timezones.forEach(timezone => { 
    let timeLocal = moment.tz(dateString, timezone);
    console.log(`Time in ${timezone}:`, timeLocal.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js">
</script>
```

Comment: The term "timezone" is used colloquially to be equivalent to "UTC offset". There are places in the US that are -7 all year round, like most parts of Arizona (but not all) and also in Canada.

Comment: Absolutely, Rob G. You're right on both scores. But that could change for any timezone. A zone that uses a fixed offset could change to using DST, using a module to convert will handle this!

Comment: If local timezones are respected, then knowledge of "UTC offsets" becomes required. Most billing companies i've come across simply circumvent the issue by utilizing their own time zone and putting that fact in their contracts.